# Can other people use add-ons I downloaded in my ps4 account on their account while on the same system?

Tags: ps4, warframe

I downloaded an add-on for warframe on my account. Can my cousin use that add-on on his account too?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify the add-on you downloaded, I'm going to assume it was something like a Prime Access pack and therefore the answer is no, you can not.

Warframe is account based and purchases are tied to your Warframe account, which takes on the name of your PSN account. While you purchase these add-ons from the PSN store, they are applied directly to your Warframe account, and are not classed as DLC on the Playstation.